# How to make CI-CD with Azure Databricks and Azure DevOps to update repos

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-databricks, continuous-deployment, databricks-repos

I'm struggling with CI-CD on Azure DevOps, we had a workflow in which we were able to use Databricks CLI command "databricks repos update" to update our repo in Databricks workspace, but we were using a user personal access token for that, now we want to change it to a service principal token using the "databricks configure --aad-token" command... but now we are getting the following error:

```
{ 'error_code': 'PERMISSION_DENIED',
'message': 'Invalid Git provider credentials. Go to User Settings > Git '
'Integration to ensure that:\n'
'1. You have entered a username with your Git provider '
'credentials.\n'
'2. You have selected the correct Git provider with your '
'credentials.\n'
'3. Your personal access token or app password has the correct '
'repo access.\n'
'4. Your personal access token has not expired.\n'
'5. If you have SSO enabled with your Git provider, be sure to '
'authorize your token.'}
```

I tried to use Terraform "databricks_git_credential" resource but I still need a PAT for that:

```
resource "databricks_git_credential" "ado" {
  git_username          = "myuser"
  git_provider          = "azureDevOpsServices"
  personal_access_token = "sometoken"
}
```

How can I achieve this? We don't want to use personal access tokens, neither from Databricks nor from Azure DevOps.